# JSF CDI Bean initialization on every page access

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm currently learning about JSF 2.0 and i dont know how to initialize something in my CDI bean everytime a jsf page is accessed ?

For example, let's say in my case, i have one CDI bean that is used in one JSF page. Somewhere inside the bean, i would like to query and  initialize something, or check authorization everytime the page is accessed (not everytime the action method is called).

I could put it into the bean's constructor, but that doesnt guarantee that the constructor would be called for every calls of the jsf page ? Or should i call using the #{myBean.initialize()} on the JSF page ?

Regards,
Albert Kam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the managed bean [`@RequestScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/RequestScoped.html), then it will be created for every HTTP request (yes, that's "everytime a JSF page is accessed" as you say in enduser's terms). You can just do the initialization job in the bean's constructor or [`@PostConstruct`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) method. This has nothing to do with CDI.

> check authorization everytime the page is accessed (not everytime the action method is called).

For that, a [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) or very maybe a [`javax.faces.event.PhaseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/JSF+Usage

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the constructor is called every time the page loads - as soon as you apply your bean to the jsf page, that object is constructed. Hence, must have a constructor without any parameters